# PAYPAL API - how to issue a refund in behalf of a 3rd party

Tags: curl, paypal

Hi,

New Paypal question here.

I am trying to implement a refund API to my website, where the API caller (me), will be able to issue a refund to a 2nd party (a buyer), in behalf of a 3rd party (a seller).

I managed to have seller's permission granted, as per [this](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/permissions-service/ht_permissions-invoice/) instructions.
Now I have the *AccessToken* and the *TokenSecret*.

I also have the PayKey and the TransactionId.

How can I construct a curl request to actually issue the refund?

Btw, I don't want to use SDKs or something, but plain curl instead.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you're working with the Adaptive Payments API, so you'd want to make a call to the [Refund API](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Refund_API_Operation/) directly.

Use your own API credentials with the seller's auth tokens and build the request based on the Refund API.

Comment: duh it's easier than i thought, however the parties didn't receive any notification about the refund, despite the json response have returned [refundStatus] => REFUNDED and [refundTransactionStatus] => COMPLETED, any clue?

Comment: Your app needs to handle that.  The best thing to do is setup an IPN solution and automate notifications to various people through that.

Comment: i tried that ipn thing, but the post message received is in a weird format, is there a way to convert the post to a php array, like a 'normal' $_POST?

Comment: IPN data is $_POST data.  For example, IPN typically sends a parameter called txn_type, so you would access that via $_POST['txn_type']